# Gulp Sass logError and gulp-notify at same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have my gulp sass task setup so it doesn't crash my `gulp watch`:

```
...
.pipe(sass({sassOptions})
  .on('error', sass.logError))
...
```

So now my Sass errors end up in the terminal but my watch task doesn't crash. Is it possible for me to utilize `gulp-notify` here as well? I tried this:

```
...
.pipe(sass({sassOptions})
  .on('error', function(err){
    notify("You have a gulp sass error");
    return sass.logError();
  }))
...
```

But this doesn't work. Apparently you have to pass `sass.logError` as the callback to the on `error` event I guess?

Is it possible to do this?

Also, related question, can I use `gulp-notify` to also throw a message when Sass successfully compiles?

Answer (score 0):

as to sass.logError try such solution:

```
gulp.task('taskName', function () {
  var self = this;
  //...
    .pipe(sass().on('error', function(err) {sass.logError.call(self, err);}))
 //..
});
```